# Bounded open interval

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, terminology

This is just a quick terminology question.

My textbook is talking about the continuity of $ f $ over a bounded open interval $ (a,b) $. Am I right in assuming that this means $a$ and $b$ are finite? Would that make an unbounded open interval $ ( - \infty, \infty )$?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, $a$ and $b$ are finite. There are other possibilities for unbounded open intervals, namely $(a, \infty)$ and $(-\infty, b)$ for $a$ and $b$ finite.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct. In the context of discussing the continuity of a function over a bounded open interval $(a, b)$, it implies that both $a$ and $b$ are finite values.

An unbounded open interval, denoted as $(-\infty, \infty)$, does not have finite boundaries and includes all real numbers. It extends infinitely in both the negative and positive directions on the real number line.

So, when considering the continuity of a function, if the interval is specified as bounded and open, it means that the interval has finite boundaries, while an unbounded open interval covers the entire real number line.